# Update source file when CSS is changed through Chrome developer tools

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, inspect-element

I'm using xampp as my local server for php projects. I'm searching for a tool to update css changes automatically which i done through chrome inspect element.

**What i'm doing now is,**

- Open my project in chrome (localhost/project)
- Right click and Inspect element
- change css (lets say change color of h1 tag)
- copy those and past it into my style.css

**What i want to do is**

- Open my project in chrome (localhost/project)
- Right click and Inspect element
- change css (lets say change color of h1 tag)
- auto update changes (change color of h1 tag) in style.css

Is there any tool or script available to achieve this ?

Comment: You want chrome to edit your server side files?

Comment: @SalmanA No only local server files.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just learnt that it is possible. Here are the instructions (or view [**this page**](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow) for up-to-date instructions):

- Open Chrome Developer Tools
- Click on **Settings** icon (the `⠇` icon at the top right corner of dev tools)
- Click on **Workspace** tab
- Click on **Add folder** button and choose the local folder that contains the desired files (e.g. `C:\www\project\`)
- If a warning appears, click **Allow**

Next step:

- Open the desired webpage (e.g. `http://localhost/project/`)
- Open the **Sources** tab in dev tools
- Open the **Navigator** panel if necessary (it is the left column in sources tab, click left triangle icon just below the top left corner of dev tools to open it)
- Scroll down to the bottom of the list where you will find the workspace folder added earlier
- Expand the folder and locate the desired file (e.g. `css/styles.css`)
- Right click on the file and choose **Map to network resource...**
- A list will popup that shows a complete or filtered list of files loaded by the webpage
- Choose the URL that corresponds to the selected local file (e.g. `http://localhost/project/css/styles.css`)
- When a warning appears about restarting dev tools, click **OK**

Now you can:

- Inspect an element and edit its CSS, the changes will be saved to local file immediately
- Edit a mapped file in source panel, the changes will be saved to local file when you **Save** the file
- Edit a mapped file in you favorite editor outside chrome; when you switch back to Chrome it will reload the file/update the styles automatically

Comment: Awesome Dude !! This is what i expected. 5 Star for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature in chrome which adresses this issue.

Here: 
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/revolutions2013/

you can read something about, how the network correspondes with your local machine and autosave the changes you make in chrome.