# fallback(to locallly hosted resources) mechanism for both css and js in case of cdn failure

Tags: jquery, html, css, cdn

Okay, before marking this question as duplicate I want you to know that I have already been to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-go) question.

I am setting up a new project and I am using

- jQuery
- Bootstrap
- masonry

Now, once my project development is complete I would like them to be loaded from a CDN however, while am in Development mode I would like to have some sort of fallback mechanism for each file, even for **CSS**, so that in case I am not connected to internet I would still be able to develop seamlessly. The mentioned question only talks about jQuery. Is there any fallback mechanism devised which takes care of all the included resources(js as well as css)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437199/provide-local-fallback-for-css-from-cdn for an example of a CSS fallback strategy.

Comment: If (i) this is just for offline testing and (ii) you test in Chrome then you can use the workspace feature in Chrome developer tools. http://stackoverflow.com/q/24156474/87015